# Interact with Iframe Using VBA

Tags: html, vba, iframe

I need to access this [website](https://agenciavirtual.light.com.br/AGV/), click in "Entrar" and then interact with the popup (that is an iframe).

And, using the URL of the iframe is not an option.

My code:

```
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim url As String

url = "https://agenciavirtual.light.com.br/AGV/"
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate url

While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

Set doc = ie.Document

Dim iframeDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set iframeDoc = doc.Frames(0).Document
If iframeDoc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "IFrame was not found."
    ie.Quit
    Exit Sub
End If

iframeDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).innertext = "123"
iframeDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")(1).innertext = "1234567890"
iframeDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")(0).Click

ie.Quit
```

The following line generates the error "Acess is denied"

```
iframeDoc = doc.Frames(0).Document
```

I've tried other ways like

```
'Generates the error "Automation Error"
IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementsbyTagName("input")(0).innerText = "123"

'Generates the error "Method 'frames' of object 'JScriptTypeInfo' failed"
IE.Document.Frames(0).Document.forms(0).innerText
```

> Main page HTML

```
<html>

<head>...</head>

<body>
<iframe class="suaIframe" src="https://suav2.light.com.br/Home/Login?DominioCanal=https://agenciavirtual.light.com.br/AGV&amp;PlataformaVersao=Z52&amp;ReturnUrl=/AGV/Autenticacao/LoginSUA&amp;Servico=8&amp;fullScreen=false"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

> Iframe HTML

```
<html>

<head>...</head>

<body>
...

<input class="itemForm" id="CPFCNPJ" maxlength="3" name="CPFCNPJ" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(this, event);" placeholder="Preencha somente com os 3 primeiros dígitos" type="tel" value="">

<input class="itemForm" id="PN" maxlength="10" name="PN" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(this, event);" placeholder="Informe o código do cliente" type="tel" value="">

<button type="button" name="btnEntrar" id="btnEntrar" class="btn btn-primary btn-entrar" value="entrar">Entrar</button>

...
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a Same-Origin issue. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy